# How can I access Vuex Store from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, vuex

I have to access a state from server. I want to change the `twitterName` with a mutation after figure out from this. I set a getter but when I try to import store to js file it sends error. How can I import a state?

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

const tweets = require('./routes/api/tweets')
const twitterName = require('./routes/api/name')

app.use('/api/tweets', tweets)
app.use('/name/', twitterName)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))
  app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

server/name.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/:twitterName', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.twitterName
  res.status(200).send(name)
})

module.exports = router
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    twitterName: 'name1234'
  },
  
  getters: {
    twitterName: (state) => state.twitterName
  }
  
  actions: {
    updateId({ commit }, id) {
      commit('setId', id)
    },
    async getTweetData({ state }) {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8081/name/' + state.twitterName)
      // do what you want with the data
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Why can't you update the state when it reaches the browser?

Comment: I want to change names from another state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use the store from the client in your express server from the simple reason that all the data used in client side of your application, including vuex store is saved in the browser, and you don’t have access to it in the server. This is not the correct way to achieve your goal.

If you want to use data from the client you need to send it to your server, so you could use it there. So if you need the `twitterName` specifically you can do something like this:

```js
router.get('/tweets/:twitterName', (req, res) => {
  // const name = 'name123'
  const name = req.params.twitterName
  T.get(
    'search/tweets',
    { from: name, count: 5 },
    function (err, data, response) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json('Oops! Something went wrong.')
      }
      data.twitterName = '<new-name>'
      res.status(200).send(data)
    }
  )
})
```

And from the vuejs store:

```js
actions: {
   async getTweetData({ state, commit }) {
       const res = await axios.get('<your-server-ip>/' + state.twitterName)
       commit('setTwitterName', res.data.twitterName)
   } 
},
mutations: {
   setTwitterName(state, newTwitterName) {
       state.twitterName = newTwitterName
   }
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for the answer. I understand the main thing but I dont understand how can I use this. I tried your suggest but I failed :) I added my server/index.js file so can you please check it and help me again?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly didn’t work? And can you add all the new relevant code?

Comment: I simplified the codes and added here. So we got backend server that named localhost.8081/name/... .  I can see in the screen what I write to url so everything is OK here. I want to set the name from vuex state with twitterName. I cant do that I am having the problem here.

Comment: Right now what you are doing is returning the same name back to the client so the name doesn’t change. 
Did your request received in the server correctly? And the response received in the client correctly?

Comment: Yes no problem from request and response. Works well. How can we change the name?

Comment: You need to send the new name back to the client, and update your state. I updated the answer hope it is clear now

Comment: Oh yes its working. Thank you very much appreciate it.